queryAllByRole('checkbox') works different depending on environment
I have a Vitest test that uses expect(screen.queryAllByRole('checkbox').length).toBeGreaterThan(0)
Running in the WebStorm test runner, the test passes. Running via nx in the terminal (and in CI) fails: nx run @member/all-products:validate:tests
Here is the project.json for the @member/all-products
"validate:tests": {
  "executor": "@nx/vite:test",
  "options": {
    "configFile": "{projectRoot}/vite.config.mts"
  }
},

Where that config file is simply
export default vite.makeConfig({
  name: '@member/all-products',
  pathToRepoRoot: '../../../',
  projectDir: __dirname,
})

Why is it failing in the terminal and passing in WebStorm?
FWIW the test failure output definitely includes checkboxes!
<label
  class="Checkbox_root__rm3qrv1 Checkbox__rm3qrv0 sprinkles_display_inlineFlex_mobile__1xrw3huey sprinkles_alignItems_flexStart_mobile__1xrw3hue2 sprinkles_flexDirection_row_mobile__1xrw3hufa sprinkles_cursor_pointer_default__1xrw3hud6 Checkbox_variants_interface__rm3qrv5 typography_Body2_Bold__185e4nvs typography_BodySpacing__185e4nv1 typography_Lato_Bold__185e4nvb typography_LatoBase__185e4nva typography_overflowWrap__185e4nv9"
  for="all-products-desktop-filters-price-On Sale"
  type="checkbox"
>
  <input
    class="Checkbox_input__rm3qrv9 Checkbox__rm3qrv8 sprinkles_position_absolute_mobile__1xrw3hunu sprinkles_zIndex_z-1__1xrw3hu2o"
    id="all-products-desktop-filters-price-On Sale"
    name="price"
    type="checkbox"
    value="On Sale"
  />
  <span

